# if an update fails in firestore at a specified path will firebase charge us for a write or read?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on cloud function where sometimes there are scenarios where it tries to update the documents that have already been deleted and I get an error as follows

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: no entity to update
```

I need to know if I try to do so will I be charged for a read or a write?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Pricing for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123560/firestore-pricing-for-deletion)

Comment: @Emmanuel no it doesn't answer my question. As I am asking for an update operation. I am trying to update a document that doesn't exist will I be charged if an update doesn't succeed that the question.

Comment: My apologies, I totally overlooked the update part, I edited my answer in order to better answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firestore you will be [charged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) for three operations: *deletes*, *reads* and *writes*.

> You are charged for each document read, write, and delete that you perform with Cloud Firestore.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) an `update` is just a write operation:

> Charges for writes and deletes are straightforward. For writes, each set or update operation counts a single write.

So now that we have established that an `update` is just a write operation (there's no reading involved), what happens when you try to `update` a record that doesn't exist? A write is a change in a document, since you're not changing anything because the document didn't exist then you won't be charged at all.